# why google play service project why not using google-play-services.jar

Tags: android, jar, admob

I was reading google new admob code integration,
they says

> b. Select Android and then click Add.... Find the
>   google-play-services_lib project and select OK to add the Google Play
>   services library.

this instruction seems odd to me, because i can add a jar file name google-play-services.jar. and it would working fine.
But as google instruction, i am wonder i may be missing something basic. 
Is it better to add a project instead of a lib jar file?

or it may have some other reason to use it as project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't ever work if you only add the jar file. You have to import the full project in your workspace, then do properly what is explained.

Jar files will never work for libraries that contain resources (like drawables, strings, etc...), which is the case of the Google Play Services lib.

You really have to import the full project and refer to it from your own project.

Comment: thanks for helping, but if i use only for admob ad implementation, that jar seems enough, i tested. may be no resources references called thats why , thank you

Comment: Take a look at the "res" directory, in the GooglePlayServices project, you'll have a list of what won't work in your project... For instance, GooglePlayServices has drawables or colors or even layouts, that won't ever be included in the jar file. So, at this moment, you don't have any problem, because your code don't use them... But, you don't know on the users phone: A dialog to notify the user doesn't have play services installed, up-to-date... You REALLY should import the project...